# Rails updating a record column is updating only part of the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an empty column called contractor_id which is of type UUID. Now im trying to update this column with another UUID for reference. Example: 173028f7-add5-4ddc-88ef-efb89ce841ba

But what's happening is, after the update, the contractor_id column just has 173028 and the rest of it isn't there! What's exactly happening?

Here's the code.

```
puts "current user id"        
puts current_user.id
#=> 173028f7-add5-4ddc-88ef-efb89ce841ba

    if Cleaner.invite!(:email => params[:email], :name => params[:name])

    Cleaner.find_by_email(params[:email]).update_attributes(contractor_id: current_user.id)
```

Here's the update query that shows in the console.

```
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "cleaners" SET "contractor_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "cleaners"."id" = $3  [["contractor_id", "173028f7-add5-4ddc-88ef-efb89ce841ba"], ["updated_at", 2017-05-15 18:22:15 +0530], ["id", "6389e05d-3158-4244-8eea-c4c343284962"]]
   (24.1ms)  COMMIT
```

So here's the schema.rb

```
 create_table "cleaners", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.uuid     "contractor_id"
 t.index ["contractor_id"], name: "index_cleaners_on_contractor_id", using: :btree


 create_table "contractors", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
```

The contractor_id was integer type. so I ran this migration to change it to uuid type so it can store uuid's. And it also reflects in the schema above as you can see.

```
def change
    remove_reference :cleaners, :contractor
    add_reference :cleaners, :contractor, foreign_key: true, index: true, type: :uuid
end
```

P.S. also, current_user.id is the id for the contractor. Just to make it clear.

Comment: do you mind sharing the definition of your `users` table ?, perhaps the `id` column is integer, or its length is not enough.

Comment: probably yes, it seems to be integer because this is what is happening internally: "173028f7-add5-4ddc-88ef-efb89ce841ba".to_i

Comment: you must change UUID to `string`

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara - The id type in both the Cleaners table and Contractors table are both of type UUID. But the contractor_id column type used to be Integer type so I ran a migration to change it to uuid. Doesn't seem to be working. Ill edit the post with that code

Comment: Well. Rails did not let me change the column type to string. Threw and error saying foreign key reference column type mismatch. So I just left it as it is as uuid and restarted my laptop. It worked after that. I just had to restart my laptop. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Yea - The answer was listed in the comments but you need to use a string for storage.

Follow the steps here for altering your table:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Well. Rails did not let me change the column type to string. Threw and error saying foreign key reference column type mismatch. So I just left it as it is as uuid and restarted my laptop. It worked after that. I just had to restart my laptop. Weird.